# Unable to deploy an AKS using GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, terraform, azure-aks, cicd

I'm trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster on Azure using the following GitLab pipeline

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:1.2.3
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/infrastructure
  TF_ADDRESS: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}

cache:
  key: my-services
  paths:
    - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform

before_script:  
  - cd ${TF_ROOT}
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

stages:
  - terraform_validate
  - terraform_plan
  - terraform_apply

terraform_validate_dev:
  stage: terraform_validate
  environment:
    name: development
  script:
    - terraform validate
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

terraform_plan_dev:
  stage: terraform_plan
  environment:
    name: development
  script:
    - terraform plan
    - terraform plan-json
  dependencies:
    - terraform_validate_dev
  artifacts:
    name: plan deployment
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"

terraform_apply_dev:
  stage: terraform_apply
  environment:
    name: development
  script:
    - terraform apply
  dependencies:
    - terraform_plan_dev
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"
      when: manual
```

but during the `terraform_plan` stage, I receive the following error:

```
"Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH."
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/343

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to find the problem.

Unfortunately, the solution proposed by @sytech did not solve the problem but helped me discover the real problem.

As a good practice, automated tools that want to deploy or use Azure services should always use service principals. For that reason, I created a service principal in Azure and was trying to use it with my Terraform code.
As the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_certificate#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform) says, to use the service principal we need to create the following environment variables:

```
ARM_CLIENT_ID
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
ARM_TENANT_ID
```

Once I added these environment variables the `terraform_plan` stage was able to complete its work.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message explains, you must [install azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

For example:

```yaml
# ...
before_script:
  - curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
  # ...
```